# How to scrape "style" attribute value in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, web-scraping, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage. I wanted to get the URL present inside the style attribute(as marked in picture)

[image]

So far I tried his but it returns me empty strings

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;


Future initiate() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://pixxelprecision.co.uk/portfolio');
  dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);

  final imgUrl = document.getElementsByClassName('w-ibanner-image');
  imgUrls = imgUrl.map((element) => element.attributes['style']).toList();

  print('URLs:  $imgUrls');

}
```

Console:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style` attribute initially has no value. Value is set by JS while page rendering. You can try to scrape `@data-bg` instead:

```
imgUrls = imgUrl.map((element) => element.attributes['data-bg']).toList();
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. But could you explain a little bit about 'data-bg' attribute cuz I can't see any attribute like this. Sorry I'm a noob so please don't mind my question. Thanks.

Comment: @FaisalShahzad When you make investigations I guess you use DOM Inspector (F12) and you see elements and attributes of already rendered web-page. But note that when you make request with `http`-tool you're getting pure HTML source page (no JavaScript executed yet). To see this HTML you need to do Right click on web page in Browser -> "View Page Source". There you can find `@data-bg` which holds required url-value

Comment: Hi, hope you are doing great. The solution you gave me is not working anymore. I have no idea what happened but now there is no "data-bg" attribute showing up in "View Page Source", and also the App give Null error because it can't find urls against 'data-bg'. I hope you had a solution for me this time also. Or is it possible to parse urls from the JavaScript loaded 'style' tag. So I don't have to worry again about this. Thanks.

Comment: @FaisalShahzad yes, now `@style` moved directly to element HTML so your initial approach should work